# MS Sql Application role cannot create server logins/db users

Tags: sql-server, database

For my application I decided that every user that is created via application and that is added to the database table Users is automatically added as a server login and database User. I figured out that it would help me keep track of logs allow me to and use Sql password policies (like password expiration).

I can insert a row into Users table with no problem and login, user and schema is added to the server/database via trigger. When I log in as a created user, I can then select, modify, delete data and create additional logins/users.

I decided to use Application role to allow all the users to have the same permissions. It works okay, but using Application role I cannot add new logins/users, I cannot reset or change their passwords either. Sql displays

```
User does not have permission to perform this action.
```

When I create new connection and not set application role, all users can create new users/logins etc.

As I'm new to Sql security, how do I grant those permissions not to users, but to the application role?

I would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Creating each db user for your application user is not gr8 idea... You mean sql user or windows user? If it is sql user how do you impersonate with your sql id dynamically from middle tier? Normally we will have one or to service accounts which used to hit database from middle tier and handle security using application layer. If you explain what you require from sql roles then we can discuss..

Comment: @KannanKandasamy Thanks for the answer. I'm creating SQL Users on the database that I'm using so I can use password expiration and logs. I have a database table "Users" that holds user data (users are essentially employees) like name, address etc. and login that corresponds to the server login and database user. All users have the same permissions on the database level and I'm handling security on application level because what user can do depends on what is set by application administrator. I know it may not be the best option and I'm open to suggestions.